# solving codingbat python list slicing

Tags: python

stuck on the following:
Return the sum of the numbers in an array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and the number that comes immediately after a 13 also does not count.

so far i've written:

```
def sum13(nums):
    if 13 not in nums:
        return sum(nums)

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 13:

            return sum(nums[:i])
```

having a problem when 13 occurs for a second time in the problem and also not counting the number immediately after it. any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: When you say `return sum(nums[:i])`, you are leaving out *all* numbers after the 13, not just the one right after it.  You could say `return sum(nums[:i]) + sum13(nums[i + 2:])`, but in the case of `sum13([4, 6, 13, 13, 4])`, the 4 would still be counted.  To fix that, you can use `return sum(nums[:i]) + sum13(nums[i + 1 + (nums[i + 1:i + 2] != [13]):])`

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it in the same style as you started with would be like this:

```
def sum13(nums):
    if 13 not in nums:
        return sum(nums)

    ret = 0
    count_next = True
    for num in nums:
        if num == 13:
            count_next = False
        elif count_next:
            ret += num
        else:
            count_next = True
    return ret
```

If the number is 13, remember to not count the next number. If next is true (ie 13 wasn't the last number) count it. If neither next is true nor the number is 13 remember to count the next number.

Comment: `next` is a built-in keyword in Python, so try to use a different variable name; I don't think it would let you write that, and if it does, it shouldn't.

Comment: @dwanderson you're right, I just had a regular python shell to try in so I didn't think of it.